# Geometric distribution with conditional expectation

Tags: probability

If $X\sim Geo(p)$ compute $E(X\mid X\geq 3)$.

I already computed this ${\displaystyle \operatorname {E} (X\mid X\geq 3)=\sum _{x\in {\mathcal {X}}}x\,P(X=x\mid X\geq 3)=\sum _{x\in {\mathcal {X}}}x\,{\frac {P(X=x,X\geq 3)}{P(X\geq 3)}},}$ but I'm stuck here. I have to take an infinite sum to compute the probabilities?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use the formula for a geometric sum. $P(X\geq 3)=\sum\limits_{k=3}^{\infty} p(1-p)^{x-1}=\frac {p(1-p)^{2}} {1-(1-p)}=(1-p)^{2}$. So $E(X|X \geq 3)= \frac {\sum\limits_{k=3}^{\infty} xp(1-p)^{x-1} } {(1-p)^{2}}$.  To find the sum in the numeartor let $f(p)=\sum\limits_{k=3}^{\infty} (1-p)^{x}$. Then $f'(p)=-\sum\limits_{k=3}^{\infty} x(1-p)^{x-1}$. Hence the numerator becomes $-pf'(p)$. Now $f(p)$ is again a geometric sum and we get $f(p)=\frac {(1-p)^{3}} {1-(1-p)}$. Now differentiate this and complete the computation.

Comment: How do you compute the first sum?

Comment: @Rey $ \sum\limits_{k=1}^{\infty} ar^{n} =\frac {ar} {1-r}$ for $|r|<1$. This is the formula for the sum of a  geometric series which you can find any Calculus book.